# Devise with token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I'm trying to authenticate by token as here:
https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6

```
class ApprovalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user_by_token!, only: [:approve]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
   @approvals = Approval.find_to_approve current_user
  end

  def approve
    approval = Approval.find(params[:id])
    approval.approve!
    ApprovalMailer.send_pdf(approval.id, current_user.id).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Approval request was approved"
debugger #here I have current_user and user_signed_in? is true
    redirect_to approvals_path
  end

  def authenticate_user_by_token!
    user_email = params[:user_email].presence
    user = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

    if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, params[:user_token])
      sign_in user, store: false
      user.renew_authentication_token!
    end
  end
end
```

I'm signed in, the `approve` method is run successfuly, but after the redirect to `approvals_path` on the last line of method `approve` it is going to the sign in page with `You need to sign in before continuing`.

Why?

Thanks

Comment: I think `user.renew_authentication_token!` made the failure. why you need renew token?

Comment: That's not the case. I just wanted to make it one-use-only, but even if I don't renew the token, still not signed in after redirection.